# error callback with {"readyState":4,"status":200,"statusText":"success"}

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have this `url` call. the url returns a json object as expected (direct browser call) but when I do that via ajax with the follow lines

```
$.ajax({
       url: url, 
       type: "GET",
       dataType:"jsonp",   
       success: function(data) {
          alert(data);
       },
       error : function(error) {
          alert("no good "+JSON.stringify(error));
       }
});
```

it returns me

```
no good {"readyState":4,"status":200,"statusText":"success"}
```

I know there's others similar questions on stackoverflow, but nobody seems solved it.

Comment: Have you validated the response data?

Comment: If it returns json then the dataType should be json not jsonp

Comment: Do you have `&callback=?` in your url?

Comment: Can you use Firebug or a similar tool (like Chrome or Safari's built in Developer Tool) to capture the actual response body and Content-Type response header, then share that with us?

Comment: JSONP is not necessary, I managed to use the normal JSON datatype fine. I'm using a restful web service that returns a JSON string for each request.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

That suggests that the HTTP request was successful but the attempt to parse the data was not.

i.e. that the data was not formatted as JSONP.

Comment: Bull's eye! So f* easy to find it out would it be if ajax could say that in error message.... that's a typical "programmer thing"...

Comment: The JS console probably had a more useful error message… but JSONP is a horrible hack in the first place (thankfully we now have CORS so we don't need to use JSONP any more).

Answer (score 5):

these changes solved my problem.

//Server side

```
echo $_GET['callback'] . '('.json_encode($data_to_encode).')';
```

//js

```
$.ajax({
       url: url+"?callback=?", 
       type: "GET",
       dataType:"jsonp",   
       success: function(data) {
          alert(data);
       },
       error : function(error) {
          alert("no good "+JSON.stringify(error));
       }
});
```

Comment: If this is your server, then why are you sending the response as JSONP? Is the server hosting from a different domain?

Comment: yes. the server hosts in a different domain. it's an "api" domain and the javascript is part of the mobile app.

Comment: But is it just the subdomain that's different? In other words is it `api.example.com` vs `www.example.com`? If so, you can still avoid JSONP.

Comment: I'm using titanium for the mobile app. so it will be mobile apps and websites. the mobile website domain will (now api is a subdomain) be a different domain.
for example: now the domains are api.example.com and the test version of mobile app is www.example.com, but once the app is completed, it will be moved into www.appdomain.com

Answer (score 1):

I've just had the exact same issue,{"readyState":4,"status":200,"statusText":"success"}

it was because I forgot to remove in my php script an echo "hello"; statment which I previously made for testing reasons, so my php script was sending a string along with JSON, that was my silly mistake maybe You have got the same too

Comment: it wasn't this issue for me. as I explained in my answer